# Android: How to pass items of a string array in a sequence

Tags: android, arrays, string, int

I have items on an array that I want to display one by one on a `TextView` and on a sequence by pressing a `Button`.

Every time I press the button, it only displays the same item.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
public void sendEqual(View view)
{
    String[] numbers = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
    int counter = 0;
    counter++;
    answer.setText(numbers[counter]);

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It always displays the same item because your counter is defined and initialized each time the button is pressed.

```
int counter = 0;
```

So `counter++` will always be 1 and whenever you click a button it will always disply the same item `numbers[1]` i.e. "`2`"
The above declaration should be outside the method. It can be a local variable of the activity/fragment. You should also declare the `numbers` variable outside the method (since it needs to be defined only once, and its not changing). Your method code should just be

```
public void sendEqual(View view)
{
    counter++;
    answer.setText(numbers[counter]);
}
```

There should also be a check condition that the counter is less than the `numbers` array length. So all in all your method would look something like this

```
public void sendEqual(View view)
{
    counter++;
    if(counter < numbers.length) {
        answer.setText(numbers[counter]);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Not sure what you mean by start at 1? I am assuming you want to show the `"1"`. You can do this as follows

```
String[] numbers = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
int counter = 0;
public void sendEqual(View view)
{
    answer.setText(numbers[counter%numbers.length]); // Taking the mod ensures that its in loop when the counter exceeds the array length
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Very helpful! Two things: is there a way to make it start at 1? And rather than stopping at the last item, how can I it make loop?  Thanks!